# openldap group membership ACL

Tags: ldap, openldap, access-control-list

When I run a search eg.

```
ldapsearch -h XX.XX.XX.XX -b 'dc=mycompany,dc=com' -D 'uid=lama,ou=people,mycompany,dc=com' -w YYYY
```

I would like to see my groups membership and not to be allowed to see other members of groups. 
I was able to make ACL which allows authenticated users to see all group members of somegroup.

```
olcAccess: {2}to dn="cn=somegroup,ou=groups,mycompany,dc=com"
  by users read
  by * none
```

I need something like selfread, just return results when value of member attrs is equal to binddn. Is it possible? 
Thx

Comment: You're sending your password in the clear over the wire. That's probably not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like the following?

```
olcAccess: to dn.regex="cn=[^,]+,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=entry by users read
olcAccess: to dn.regex="cn=[^,]+,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=member by dnattr=member selfread
```

Comment: Why would you use a regex and not a simple children or subtree?  `dn.children="ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"` The regex seems overkill, and less readable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
olcAccess: to dn.regex="cn=[^,]+,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=entry,objectClass
  by users read
  by * none
olcAccess: to dn.regex="cn=[^,]+,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" attrs=member
  by dnattr=member selfread
  by * none
```